Moving files from GoogleDrive folder works manually but not automatically
I have some working code that copies files from local google drive folders into some other local folders.
def move_files(source_dirs, dest_dirs, file_patterns):
    """Move files from source directories to destination directories based on patterns."""
    if any("GoogleDrive" in dir for dir in source_dirs + dest_dirs):
        pause_sync_gdrive()

    filepaths = []  # List of new paths (destination paths)
    original_destinations = []  # List of original paths
    dest_dir_cycle = itertools.cycle(dest_dirs)  # Iterator that cycles through dest_dirs

    for source_dir in source_dirs:
        for pattern in file_patterns:
            for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, pattern)):
                try:
                    # Get the next destination directory from the cycle
                    dest_dir = next(dest_dir_cycle)
                    dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.basename(filename))
                    os.rename(filename, dest_path)
                    filepaths.append(dest_path)
                    original_destinations.append(filename)
                except OSError as e:
                    logging.error(f"Failed to move file from {filename} to {dest_path}: {e}")
                    log_environment()  # Log environmental variables at the start
                    investigate_file_lock(filename)  # Investigate the file lock

    if any("GoogleDrive" in dir for dir in source_dirs + dest_dirs):
        resume_sync_gdrive()

    return filepaths, original_destinations

This runs perfectly when I run the script manually. However, when this is launched by crontab, I always get resource deadlock errors:
Failed to move file from /Users/machine/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-Account1@gmail.com/My Drive/AUTOProc/testfile.pdf to /Users/machine/UTILS/ToProcess/testfile.pdf: [Errno 11] Resource deadlock avoided: '/Users/machine/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-Account1@gmail.com/My Drive/AUTOProc/testfile.pdf' -> '/Users/machine/UTILS/ToProcess/testfile.pdf'

I already log the environment Settings: System-wide power settings: Currently in use: standby              0 Sleep On Power Button 1 autorestart          0 SleepServices        0 powernap             0 networkoversleep     0 disksleep            10 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by powerd) ttyskeepawake        1 displaysleep         0 tcpkeepalive         1 womp                 0
and obtain lsof info through subprocess.run(['lsof', filename], capture_output=True, text=True)but I get this
No lsof output for /Users/machine/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-Account1@gmail.com/My Drive/AUTOProc/testfile.pdf. File might not be locked. 

Any idea on what might be the issue?
